# Trace of a function on an elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, elliptic-curves, trace

Let $K/F$ be a Galois extension of number fields with Galois group $G$. Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over $F$ and $f \in K(E)^{\times}$ be a function.

Define the trace of $f$ to be $Tr_{K/F}(f)= \sum\limits_{g \in G} g(f)$. If $f$ is nonconstant, then can its trace ever be $0$? If so, can you give me any necessary conditions for this to happen?

**EDIT:** I wish to assume that *some* nonzero coefficient of $f$ lies in $F$, although I'm not sure whether I would need one in both the numerator and denominator to prevent the trace being zero. This is to prevent cases like Jykri's example below.

Comment: If $E$ is defined over $F=\Bbb{Q}$, say by $y^2=x^3+Ax+B$, and $K=F[\sqrt2]$, wouldn't something like $f=\sqrt2 x$ work? Not really an exciting example, but anyway?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I was thinking this wasn't true for number fields but what if some nonzero coefficient of the numerator lies in $F$? I'll edit my question accordingly.

Comment: What if you take the trace of $f-f'$ where $f,f'$ are in the same Galois orbit? Also, to get a class of silly examples accompanying @JyrkiLahtonen's nice one, you can note that your trace map sends $E(K)$ to $E(F)$. So, if $E(F)=\{0\}$ then... :)

Comment: @AlexYoucis the question came about as I wanted to know whether the trace of two such functions being equal meant they were Galois conjugates and rewrote it to consider the difference but obviously forgot to mention that. What I was hoping was that this would be a necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: The case of $E(F)$ being trivial is something I hadn't considered though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have now found an answer so I shall post it here and if anyone spots any mistakes then please let me know.

As Alex pointed out above, if $f,f'$ are in the same Galois orbit then the trace of $f-f'$ is certainly zero and I believe that this is only case.

Since $K/F$ is Galois, $K(E)/F(E)$ is also a Galois extension of function fields of the same degree $n$ and isomorphic Galois groups. We may then apply the normal basis theorem which states that the exists $\alpha \in K(E)$ such that the set $\{ g(\alpha) | g \in Gal(K(E)/F(E)) \}$ form a basis for the extension $K(E)/F(E)$.

Now the image of the trace map is nonzero so has rank $1$ as an $F(E)$ vector space. This means the kernel has dimension $n-1$ by rank-nullity theorem.

Notice that the set $\{ \alpha - g(\alpha) | g \in Gal(K(E)/F(E)) \}$ is linearly independent and has size $n-1$. Since every element is in the kernel, this must be a basis and so any element of the kernel has the form $f-g(f)$ as claimed.